# How to apply word2vec for k-means clustering?

Tags: scala, cluster-analysis, text-mining, word2vec, dl4j

I am new to word2vec. With applying this method, I am trying to form some clusters  based on words extracted by word2vec from scientific publications' abstracts. To this end, I have first retrieved sentences from the abstracts via stanfordNLP and put each sentence into a line in a text file. Then the text file required by deeplearning4j word2vec was ready to process (http://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec).

Since the texts come from scientific fields, there are a lot of mathematical terms or brackets. See the sample sentences below:

```
The meta-analysis showed statistically significant effects of pharmacopuncture compared to conventional treatment = 3.55 , P = .31 , I-2 = 16 % ) . 

90 asymptomatic hypertensive subjects associated with LVH , DM , or RI were randomized to receive D&G herbal capsules 1 gm/day , 2 gm/day , or identical placebo capsules in double-blind and parallel fashion for 12 months .
```

After preparing the text file, I have run word2vec as below:

```
SentenceIterator iter = new LineSentenceIterator(new File(".../filename.txt"));
        iter.setPreProcessor(new SentencePreProcessor() {
            @Override
            public String preProcess(String sentence) {
                //System.out.println(sentence.toLowerCase());
                return sentence.toLowerCase();
            }
        });


        // Split on white spaces in the line to get words
        TokenizerFactory t = new DefaultTokenizerFactory();
        t.setTokenPreProcessor(new CommonPreprocessor());

        log.info("Building model....");
        Word2Vec vec = new Word2Vec.Builder()
                .minWordFrequency(5)
                .iterations(1)
                .layerSize(100)
                .seed(42)
                .windowSize(5)
                .iterate(iter)
                .tokenizerFactory(t)
                .build();

        log.info("Fitting Word2Vec model....");
        vec.fit();

        log.info("Writing word vectors to text file....");

        // Write word vectors
        WordVectorSerializer.writeWordVectors(vec, "abs_terms.txt");
```

This script creates a text file containing many words withe their related vector values in each row as below:

```
pills -4.559159278869629E-4 0.028691953048110008 0.023867368698120117 ...
tricuspidata -0.00431067543104291 -0.012515762820839882 0.0074045853689312935 ...
```

As a subsequent step, this text file has been used to form some clusters via k-means in spark. See the code below:

```
    val rawData = sc.textFile("...abs_terms.txt")
    val extractedFeatureVector = rawData.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').slice(2,101).map(_.toDouble))).cache()

    val numberOfClusters = 10
    val numberOfInterations = 100

    //We use KMeans object provided by MLLib to run
    val modell = KMeans.train(extractedFeatureVector, numberOfClusters, numberOfInterations)

    modell.clusterCenters.foreach(println)


    //Get cluster index for each buyer Id
    val AltCompByCluster = rawData.map {
      row=>
        (modell.predict(Vectors.dense(row.split(' ').slice(2,101)
          .map(_.toDouble))),row.split(',').slice(0,1).head)
    }

    AltCompByCluster.foreach(println)
```

As a result of the latest scala code above, I have retrieved 10 clusters based on the word vectors suggested by word2vec. However, when I have checked my clusters no obvious common words appeared. That is, I could not get reasonable clusters as I expected. Based on this bottleneck of mine I have a few questions:

1) From some tutorials for word2vec I have seen that no data cleaning is made. In other words, prepositions etc. are left in the text. So how should I apply cleaning procedure when applying word2vec?

2) How can I visualize the clustering results in a explanatory way?

3) Can I use word2vec word vectors as input to neural networks? If so which neural network (convolutional, recursive, recurrent) method would be more suitable for my goal?

4) Is word2vec meaningful for my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: k-means is not expected to work well in high-dimensional spaces. You should also try ELKIs k-means which is much better than Sparks (and much faster). But *interpreting* clusters is probably the hardest part. You eill likely see irrelevant words everywhere.